# How do you control TrackBallControls rotation in three.js

Tags: javascript, controls, three.js

I have been making [**this**](http://0xor1.github.io/Sudoku-Assistant-3D/) app, if you click the top left tab it will show the assistant cube and then click and drag your mouse around the screen to move the camera with the trackBallControls. If you rotate the camera off to one side and then click the top left tab again to hide the assistant cube it should go back to focusing on the board, which it does but it is rotated at an odd angle.

Is there any part of the trackBallControls api that allows for the rotating of the camera? Currently I animate the camera back to centre and zero rotation but after the rotation animation has finished the trackBallControls takes over again and snaps it out of alignment, which is unwanted and I can't see any obvious way of controlling rotation from the control api.

Comment: Thank you very much :), it's my first website ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no part of `TrackballControls` that constrains the rotation of the camera.

`TrackballControls` is really the wrong control for your purposes. This is why you are not liking it. Try `OrbitControls`, which will keep the puzzle "right side up" -- plus the code is easy to understand.

Personally, I would do as you say, and write your own controls. IMHO, the camera does not need to move vertically within the assistant -- just in a circle horizontally.

In any event, Congratulations! Nice looking app. :-)

Comment: thanks @WestLangley, I tried using orbit controls but it doesn't seem to fit my needs when I drag vertically it moves the camera as I want in by increasing the theta angle (assuming physics spherical polar coords), but dragging horizontally the camera just rotates on its own viewing axis rather than actually rotating around the world z-axis (or phi in physics spherical polar coords). I'll do as you suggest and roll my own controls. Thanks again.

Comment: Huh? In OrbitControls, the camra rotates around `controls.center`, not "on it's own viewing axis" -- at least, that is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: If I make the orbit controls centre the middle of the board the cameras position is updated correctly when being moved vertically (theta angle) but the phi angle doesn't move the camera horizontally around the z axis of the game board it just rotates around its LookAt axis if that makes any more sense. so the camera just spins rather than pans. I apologise for my lack of concise technical vocabulary. I'll figure it out with my own control anyway, thanks for your advice.

Comment: the solution was just to reset `camera.up` back to new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0) after I had animated the position and rotation of the camera, because trackball controls updates `position` `rotation` and `up`. All sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code of `this.rotateCamera()` in `TrackballControls.js`.

Comment: I can, but I don't want to modify the control as I don't fully understand its implementation, for that reason I'm currently writing my own type of control from scratch, but I was hoping there would be a simple way of doing it with the api provided for trackBall. thanks.